# Graph Isomorphism Problem and ZKP

Tags: graph-isomorphism

the question I need help in explaining is this -

Outline how the Graph Isomorphism Problem can be used to construct a zero-knowledge proof.

and

Justification for why your scenario meets the requirements for being a zero knowledge
proof.

I do not understand how this works. if someone could lead me in the correct direction that would be nice.

Comment: What do you know about ZKP and graph isomorphism?

Comment: Zero knowledge problem is an interactive protocol used between two parties: the prover and the verifier. The prover may want to prove that something is what it says to be to the verifier without revealing the main information of that message. Graph isomorphism is when there is two graphs that are structurally the same besides the reordering of labels. It includes same amount of vertices, edges and must have the same degree.

Comment: That is good for a bare minimum, ,but what is the key idea that make graph isomorphism suited to the protocol? Why not some other isomorphism problem? For example, why not two sets having a bijection between them?

Comment: Did you mind explaining this a bit more. I have done some bijection stuff. I just don't really see how that relates to the question.

Comment: What I mean is that bijection between sets is the equivalent of graph isomorphism. Why use graph isomorphism instead of set isomorphism? There must be something different about graph isomorphism.